# Changing list answers in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, list, string-formatting

I've been trying to input into a mysql table using python, thing is I'm trying to create a list with all dates from April 2016 to now so I can insert them individually into the sql insert, I searched but I didn't find how can I change value per list result (if it's 1 digit or 2 digits):

```
dates = ['2016-04-'+str(i+1) for i in range(9,30)]
```

I would like `i` to add a `0` every time `i` is a single digit (i.e 1,2,3 etc.)
and when its double digit for it to stay that way (i.e 10, 11, 12 etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using C style formatting, all the dates in April:

> dates = ['2016-04-%02d'%i for i in range(1,31)]

Need range(1,31) since the last value in the range is not used, or use range(30) and add 1 to i.

The same using .format():

> dates = ['2016-04-{:02}'.format(i) for i in range(1,31)]

Answer (score 1):

```
dates = ['2016-04-'+ '{:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(9,30)]

>>> print dates
['2016-04-09', '2016-04-10', '2016-04-11', '2016-04-12', '2016-04-13', '2016-04-14', '2016-04-15', '2016-04-16', '2016-0
4-17', '2016-04-18', '2016-04-19', '2016-04-20', '2016-04-21', '2016-04-22', '2016-04-23', '2016-04-24', '2016-04-25', '
2016-04-26', '2016-04-27', '2016-04-28', '2016-04-29']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dateutil module

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY
start_date = datetime(2016,04,01)
w=[each.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for each in list(rrule(freq=DAILY, dtstart=start_date, until=datetime(2016,05,9)))]
```